# Java 8 - Filter a string-X from a list using startsWith and Save the String-X to a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and trying to get my head around how streams and filter works with list. I have a list of predefined strings and I have a string value which I am processing. I want to add the processed string to a new list if the string starts with any of the strings in the predefined list. If the string doesn't match any strings from the list then save it to another list.

For example:

```
List<String> internalIpAddresses= new ArrayList<>();
List<String> externalIpAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> ipAddresseses = new ArrayList<String>();
ipAddresses.add("10.");
ipAddresses.add("132.174.");
ipAddresses.add("192.168.");

// filter internal ip addresses
for(String ipAddress : ipAddresseses){

     if("10.11.12.13".startsWith(ipAddress)) {
          internalIpAddresses.add("10.11.12.13");
     }
}

// filter external ip addresses
for(String ipAddress : ipAddresseses){

     if(!"5.6.7.8".startsWith(ipAddress)) {
          externalIpAddresses .add("5.6.7.8");
     }
}
```

Result:

```
internalIpAddresses: 10.11.12.13
externalIpAddresses : 5.6.7.8
```

Is there a way this can be achieved in a simpler way using stream in java 8?

Like:

```
ipAddresseses.stream()
     .filter(ipAddress -> clientIpAddress.startsWith(ipAddress)
     .*if the clientIpAddress starts with any of the values in the list then add to internalIpAddresses List
     .*if clientIpAddress doesn't start with any values in list then add to externalIpAddresses List
```

In the end I want to save the `clientIpAddress` ("10.11.12.13" or "5.6.7.8"), not the values from the `ipAddresses` ("10." or "192.168.") list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply, your iterative code using streams could be represented as :

```
List<String> ipAddresses = Arrays.asList("10.", "132.174.", "192.168.");

List<String> internalIpAddresses = ipAddresses.stream()
        .filter("10.11.12.13"::startsWith)
        .map(ipAddress -> "10.11.12.13")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> externalIpAddresses = ipAddresses.stream()
        .filter(ipAddress -> !"5.6.7.8".startsWith(ipAddress)) // I doubt this should be '.filter("5.6.7.8"::startsWith)'
        .map(ipAddress -> "5.6.7.8")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A general approach as suggested in comments for solving this could be using:

```
List<String> internalIpAddresses = Stream.of("10.11.12.13") // can add more addresses
        .filter(ip -> ipAddresses.stream().anyMatch(ip::startsWith))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That’s a strange way to process single items. When considering these items as a special case of a general-purpose code, it would make more sense to use, e.g. `List<String> internalIpAddresses = Stream.of("10.11.12.13").filter(ip -> ipAddresses.stream().anyMatch(prefix -> ip.startsWith(prefix)).collect(toList());`, which allows to insert more addresses to be checked by the operation.

Comment: @Holger true, updated and learned for a generic approach. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can try :

```
ipAddresseses.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(ipAddress -> ipAddress.startsWith("10.11.12.13")));
```

This will give a Map with two elements, one with good ipAddress and one with bad.

Comment: I did. That returned me a list with value as "10."
I want to save the `clientIpAddress` to the list not `ipAddress` from `ipAddresses`

Comment: I've fixed this part in my example code to `ipAddress -> "10.11.12.13".startsWith(ipAddress)`. The Map in your code, can it have "10.11.12.13" as true because it's starting with one of the values in ipAddresses List? Or add "5.6.7.8" as false since it doesn't start with any values in ipAddresses.

Comment: I am not sure why the peer reviewers rejected my changes in your comment but could you please let me know if my description still makes sense to you?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this -

```
  ipAddresseses.stream().foreach( ipaddress 
 -> decideGoodOrBadAndAdd(s);
```

Create one method which will check if it's good or bad ip address and add it in respective list accordingly-

```
  public void decideGoodOrBadAndAdd(String 
  ipaddress){

  if("10.11.12.13".startsWith(ipAddress)) {
        goodIpAddresses.add(ipAddress);
   }
  else if(!"5.6.7.8".startsWith(ipAddress)) {
        badIpAddresses.add(ipAddress);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is going to add 10.11.12.13 to badIpAddress when the forEach loop is processing "192.168." or "132.174." from the ipAddressesList.

That's the reason in the example I have two separate loops with two conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using :

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> ipMap = ipAddresses.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(ipAddress -> ipAddress.startsWith("10.")));

goodIpAddresses.addAll(ipMap.get(true));
badIpAddresses.addAll(ipMap.get(false));
```

Here the map *ipMap* will contain only two keys depending on the predicate in [**`partitioningBy()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-)

To fetch the ip's needed to be added to the `goodIpAddresses` just use the key *true* and to fetch the ip's for `badIpAddresses` use the key *false*.

Comment: This is interesting. However, nowhere in ipMap I can find "10.11.12.13" which is the good ip address I want to add to goodIpAddresses List. Also, I've fixed my example code with `ipAddress -> "10.11.12.13".startsWith(ipAddress)`